# UIPageViewController stops scrolling after receiving a press

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller, tvos

I have a plain `UIPageViewController` with a data source, in a tvOS project. The swipes for going to previous/next page work fine, but only until I press the “select” button (`UIPressType.Select`, pressing down the touch pad on the Siri Remote). From that moment on the swipes don’t work anymore, the page view controller just stays on the current page.

There are no custom gesture recognizers, I don’t override any of the press or touch input methods. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D-oh, it’s just a simulator glitch. After pressing Return on the keyboard, the arrow keys no longer switch pages, but the Siri Remote gestures work fine.